# ProGuard: Warning: butterknife.internal.InjectViewProcessor:

Tags: android

I faced this error during generating apk using idea13

```
ProGuard:  Warning: butterknife.internal.InjectViewProcessor: can't find superclass or interface javax.annotation.processing.AbstractProcessor
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Even though you didn't post an actual question, I'm assuming you want that warning gone.

Add the following lines to your ProGuard configuration:

```
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}
```

[source](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/)

Comment: If we're keeping the butterknife classes, why do we need the -dontwarn line? Why are warnings still coming up?

Comment: Be aware that  "-keepnames class *" will mean that NONE of your  class names will be obfuscated.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone does face an issue with Proguard and Butterknife, use the following given at http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/index.html#proguard

```
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```

Comment: These instructions from the ButterKnife's web worked, thanks. Now time to face the rest of errors with retrofit etc :P

Comment: Add these to your proguard-project.txt file in the section # Dont warn

Comment: The link (http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/index.html#proguard) appears to be broken and the main page (http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) does not appear to mention Proguard; are these rules still necessary?